# How to remove duplicate values from a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I don't know how can best describe my problem but here it is, I'm trying to remove the same names(values) from `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

for example if this map contain names like

```
    map.put("Vivaldi","Antonio");
    map.put("Belucci", "Monica");
    map.put("Gudini", "Harry");
    map.put("Verdo", "Dhuzeppe");
    map.put("Maracci", "Bruno");
    map.put("Carleone", "Vito");
    map.put("Bracco", "Luka");
    map.put("Stradivari", "Antonio");
```

I want to remove all entries with the value "Antonio" from it by using method `removeTheFirstNameDuplicates`, I looked in Google for a couple of days and all examples are close to what I want but not really what I need.

My thoughts are, I need something that will check a map and if it contains the same values in it then remove the duplicate. But how can I do this?

Comment: [Iterate over entries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46905/2071828) and remove the ones you don't like.

Comment: Your map should probably be reversed, and be a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the keys are the first names, and the values are lists of names. What do you use this map for? Are you sure you shouldn't have a `List<Musician>` instead?

Comment: This is method which creates map of names

Comment: @JBNizet I think Stradivari was a luthier rather than a musician. ;)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: given the quality of his violins, he probably was a TDD addict. Testing his violins effectively makes him a musician, doesn't it? :-)

Comment: I don't know if I can play violin or not... I've never tried

Comment: @Bohemian you got elected then? Congratulations!

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks! :) It was a landslide actually. I was quite surprised. But let   me share something... it ain't glamorous - there's plenty of work, and not much time for answering questions any more

Comment: I know how work iterator but how can make hem check if there are same values in map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with the following method which only iterates over the map once:

```
private static void removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(final Map<String, String> map) {
    final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    final HashSet<String> valueSet = new HashSet<String>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        final Entry<String, String> next = iter.next();
        if (!valueSet.add(next.getValue())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

The `add()` method on `HashSet` will return `false` if a value has already been added to the set. The method above uses this to detect that a duplicate has been found and then removes the duplicate from the `HashMap` by using the `remove()` method on the iterator.

It is worth noting that, depending on the `Map` implementation you use, the iteration order may not be guaranteed so which duplicate you remove is also not guaranteed.

If you were to use a `TreeMap` rather than a `HashMap` you would be certain to iterate over the map alphabetically by key e.g. Berluccio, Bracco, Carleone … Verdo. You would then always keep Stradivari and remove Vivaldi.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    java.util.Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterate = map.entrySet()
            .iterator();
    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
        Entry mapEntry = iterate.next();
        String key = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();

        values.add(value);
        keys.add(key);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        if (Collections.frequency(values, values.get(i)) > 1) {
            map.remove(keys.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Comment: Is each call to `Collections.frequency()` going to iterate over the entire list?

Comment: Yup. Its on the fly thinking. There could be a better/shorter solution.