# How to remove all the mappings of a particular object in java hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a **many-to-one** mapping in java hashmap. I iterate through all the values by using `java.util.HashMap.values()`. Now if I want to delete a particular value and all the corresponding keys, then what should I do?

Will just using `java.util.HashMap.remove(Object key)` with one of the keys suffice?

Comment: yes, it's enough to remove all values that bind on the key

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269271/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example you can remove the values from a map without iteration.

**Code**

```
// The test map
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Key1", "Value");
map.put("Key2", "Value");
map.put("Key3", "Value");

// Remove the map. The collection is necessary to remove all values instead of just one.
map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton("Value"));

// Print the map to confirm it worked.
System.out.println("Printing Map");
for(final String key : map.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key + " = " + map.get(key));
}
```

**Output**

```
Printing Map
```

Comment: Was about to post something very similar.  I had two values, x & y.  The remove line was `map.values().removeIf(y::equals);`.  Same result.

Comment: That is useful if you are using Java 8+